# Log ActionMailer mails in files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Is there a way to save ActionMailer mails to files as a way of logging the sent mails upon delivery?

I have a lot of e-mails that go missing and would like to log the sent mails in files (i.e., I want my web site admin to look through the e-mails, so storing them in files besides having them in my general log file would be helpful in implementing a user-friendly solution).

If I can access the contents and addressees of a sent mail, then I can save them to files, but I cannot find a clear way to access the contents of an e-mail from within ActionMailer.

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696627/best-way-to-log-actionmailer-sent-emails-in-a-database) but the only answer there doesn't help me to solve this problem, some pointers or actual code to implement this would be really helpful.

Thank you.